# Visual C++ Compiler Producing Inaccessible .pyd Files

Tags: python, c++, visual-c++

All of a sudden, my compiler seems to have stopped functioning. I am building C++ extensions for Python (3.5) from scratch and compiling them from the command line using the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. It was working fine this morning, then out of nowhere started throwing linker errors relating to the .pyd file that was being produced.

In a Windows 7 command line (PowerShell, actually), I run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This throws the error:
"LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Z:\ ...\wrapperModule.cp35-win_amd64.pyd" (wrapperModule is the name of the extension module).

I don't have permission to access the file listed above and can't seem to force permission, either. Before this issue started, I was able to access the .pyd file without any problem.

UPDATE:
It turns out copying the directory containing the source code to a local location (the code was on a shared network drive) solved the problem. This code is a part of a git repository on the shared drive and needs to remain there, however.

Comment: Can you temporarily disable your anti-malware software to preclude that as part of the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is on my work machines, and I do not have the ability to disable that software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it had nothing to do with the compiler (probably unsurprisingly) and everything to do with Windows' handling of permission. I noticed that I was unable to delete the file from either of my machines, so I decided to shut one of them down as it seemed immediately clear that it was probably the two computers somehow fighting over rights to the file. The file immediately disappeared and all problems went with it.